# Default mount options differ?

Tags: linux, fstab

I usually mount my drives via `fstab` with the option "defaults". Today, out of curiosity, I checked what options that actually would set `mount`.

Now what kind of surprised me was that my EXT4 drive only would show up with the options `(rw,relatime)`. However, according to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount), the defaults should actually set `rw`, `suid`, `dev`, `exec`, `auto`, `nouser`, `async`, and `relatime`.

Is there a reason why these other options wouldn't show up when checking with the `mount` command?

Comment: (1) It seems `mount` omits some default values. E.g. for each mount its either `suid` or `nosuid`, but you can see only the latter in the output of `mount`. Even `mount -o remount,suid …` does not make `suid` appear, it only makes `nosuid` *disappear*. No citation, so not an answer. (2) [`linux.die.net` is probably not the best source](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3710/108618) . Modern `man 8 mount` states "Note that the real set of all default mount options depends on the kernel and filesystem type". Additionally "the listing mode is maintained for backward compatibility only".